# exec redirects in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, output

I write a lot of non-interactive scripts where I would like all output to go to a log file and have nothing appear on-screen.

To solve this, I've been using:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec &> logfile
echo "Step One:"
/some/command/one
echo "Step Two:"
/some/command/two
```

I want to make sure this is a sane method.

Are there any significant drawbacks or issues I'm going to encounter if I move forward with this methodology?  If so, what are they and how best can they be mitigated (including by changing my methodology).

Comment: What you wrote is a common programming pattern. Only - even though you target it specifically for bash - I'd use the portable syntax for &> . The little typing overhead should be tolerable since you need that code only in one place.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Redirection of command output to a log file

Redirecting all command output (including error messages) to a log file
is standard practice for non-interactive shell scripts.  
It’s particularly useful to have a record of command output for scripts
that are run by cron or triggered by some other external event,
and there are no downsides in such use-cases.

Many of my shell scripts include the following lines near the start:

```
exec 1>>"$logfile"
exec 2>&1
```

The order that these redirection commands is important. The first `exec` command redirects all writes to the `stdout` (1) stream to append (`>>`) to the log file. The second command redirects all writes to the `stderr` (2) stream to the same file descriptor that `stdout` (1) currently points to. Using only one file descriptor for accessing a file ensures that the writes happen in the desired order.

If using Bash, you can combine these commands into a single construct that does the same thing:

```
exec &>>"$logfile"
```

If you want the log file to be cleared of previous entries each time the script is run, use only a single `>` redirection operator (over-writes the previous contents):

```
exec &>"$logfile"
```

Use of the `exec` builtin for input/output redirection is specified by the POSIX definition for the [Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec),
and the `exec` builtin is available in any POSIX compatible shell.

#### Redirection while running an interactive shell

You can experiment with redirecting standard output to a file while in a temporary/disposable interactive shell session.  After running `exec 1>outfile`, all future commands print their output to `outfile` instead of to the terminal.

You can also experiment with redirecting standard error in an interactive shell session, but it can make the interactive shell session very hard to work with.

After running `exec 2>errorfile`, the standard error produced by any further commands is written to the redirected error file – as expected. However, the problem is that *from now on*, the shell (Bash in this case) prints its prompt to this file and any text typed as a command is also redirected to this file. 
Some shells (such as Bash) also echo characters received by `stdin` to `stderr`. 
In others, such as `dash`, for the rest of the shell session,
you’re essentially working blind, as nothing at all is sent to the terminal. 
This obviously makes it *very difficult* to continue interacting with the shell.

As [Orion points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184125/exec-redirects-in-bash/184217#comment307067_184217) and [Scott says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184807/80216),
you can store references to the default `stdout` and `stderr` file descriptors
before trying any such experiments using `exec 3>&1` and `exec 4>&2`
respectively. 
When you’ve finished your experiments,
you can restore printing to standard error by running `exec 2>&4`
and restore printing to standard output with `exec 1>&3`.

For interactive use,
I’d advise redirecting standard out and standard error streams
on a command-by-command basis:
`>> outfile 2>&1 command with arguments`.

Comment: If you are afraid of "dropping" the file descriptors, you can always save them. Use `3>&1`, `4>&2` and then you can always go `1>&3`, `2>&4` when you want them back.

Comment: Anthony, can you elaborate more on how you might lose your shell session?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain how redirecting `stderr` makes it *very difficult* to continue interacting with the shell. I've also incorporated the tip for storing file descriptors (thanks, @orion).