# suppress stderr messages in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, stderr

Consider the following (slightly silly) script name 'test1.sh':

```
#/bin/bash
#
sleep 10 &
echo sleep pid = $!
pkill sleep
```

When I run it, I get not only the output of the echo, but bash's reporting of the death of sleep on stderr:

```
$ ./test1.sh
sleep pid = 3551
./test1.sh: line 5:  3551 Terminated              sleep 10
```

In this case, I'd like to suppress the printout to stderr.  I know I can do it on the command line, as in:

```
$ ./test1.sh 2> /dev/null
```

... but is there a way to suppress it from *within* the script?   (I know I could wrap it in a second script and have the wrapper redirect it, but there must be something easier...)

Comment: did you try adding the redirect 2> /dev/null after the pkill sleep ?

Comment: @rahul: yes I did -- pkill isn't generating the message, bash is.

Comment: I used kill instead of pkill and do not get the stderr. strange..

Comment: @rahul: could it be a built in vs non-built in thing?  Did you try it with pkill as well?

Comment: yes, i believe it is. I get the same error with pkill, but not with kill. While using kill, i used the pid instead of the proc name.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You're right; pkill isn't generating the message, bash is. 
You suggest that

```
$ ./test1.sh 2> /dev/null
```

is a possible solution. 
As UVV points out, the equivalent action from within the script is

```
exec 2> /dev/null
```

This redirects the stderr for the script to `/dev/null`
from this statement until it is changed back. 
Clumsy ways of changing it back include

```
exec 2> /dev/tty
```

which redirects stderr to the terminal. 
This is probably (but not necessarily) where it was originally.

Or

```
exec 2>&1
```

which sets stderr to be the same as stdout, and is likely to be wrong.

A more reliable way is

```
exec 3>&2
exec 2> /dev/null
(do stuff where you don't want to see the stderr.)
exec 2>&3
```

which saves the original stderr in file descriptor 3, and later restores it.

Other ways to suppress just the announcement of the process death include

```
(sleep 10 & pkill sleep) 2> /dev/null
```

and

```
{ sleep 10 & pkill sleep;} 2> /dev/null
```

which change the stderr for only the grouped commands.

Comment: Are there any dangers associated with saving `stdin` and `stderr` to new file descriptors, sending the original descriptors to `/dev/null` and then restoring them?

Comment: Well, I suppose that, if you ran a program that (unbeknownst to you) wrote to file descriptor 3 (or 4), that operation would fail under normal circumstances.  But the program could be written to ignore the failure and carry on without reporting it; then you’d never know.  But if your file descriptor 1 (or 2) was “parked” on file descriptor 3 (or 4), then that program would suddenly be writing to your script’s stdout or stderr.  But that’s a very contrived example, and still minimal danger.   Did you have something in mind?

Comment: FWIW, I favor Scott's grouped command approach, i.e. `{ sleep 10 & pkill sleep;} 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Running `exec 2> /dev/null` appears to also disable local echo in Bash 5.x (no prompt and no characters printed on screen when typing.)

Answer (score 13):

According to [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ioredirintro.html) you could do something like following:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 2>/dev/null
ls -al test
```