# Bash: turn stderr back on after suppressing

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, io, stderr

I've made this script which automates installing/uninstalling git.  In my function for testing if git is installed, I use the `git --version` command and test the return code.

I dislike the stderr output that occurs normally as I'm trying to make a nice custom output.  Though I've figured out how to suppress stderr just for this function, I can't seem to reactivate it.

My `read` prompt is now missing after calling this function.

```
function CheckGit() {
    exec 3>&2           # link file desc 3 w/ stderr
    exec 2> /dev/null

    SILENT_MODE=$1

    if [[ ! $(git --version) ]]; then
        if [ SILENT_MODE ]; then
            printf "${LT_RED} GIT IS NOT INSTALLED.\n"
        fi
        continue;
    else
        if [ SILENT_MODE ]; then
            printf "${LT_BLUE} GIT IS CURRENTLY INSTALLED.\n"
        fi
        continue;
    fi
    GIT_INSTALLED=$?
    #turn back on the stderr notifications
    exec 2>&3 3>&-      # Restore stdout and close file descriptor #3
}

while true; do
    printf "${LT_BLUE} Menu\n"
    printf " ***********************************************\n"
    printf "${LT_GREEN} a) Check git.\n"
    printf "${LT_GREEN} b) (More to be added)\n"
    printf "${LT_GREEN} c) ...\n"
    printf "${LT_GREEN} d) ...\n"
    printf "${LT_GREEN} h) ...\n"
    printf "${LT_RED} x) Exit.\n"
    printf "\n${NC}"
    read -p "Please make a selection: " eotuyx
    case $eotuyx in
        [Aa]* ) CheckGit true; continue;;
        [Bb]* ) ...; continue;;
        [Cc]* ) ...; continue;;
        [Dd]* ) ...; continue;;
        [Hh]* ) ...; continue;;
        [XxQq]* ) break;;
        * ) -e "\n${NC}" + "Please answer with a, b, c, d, x(or q).";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: This might be of use to you. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184804/suppress-stderr-messages-in-a-bash-script

Comment: you should get rid of those `continue` inside the `CheckGit` function. Those kind of "nonlocal gotos" are not only terribly confusing, but they also don't work the same in all shells: try this with dash, bash, zsh and ksh: `sh -c 'foo(){ continue; }; for a in 1 2 3; do foo; echo $a; done'`

Comment: also, `if [ SILENT_MODE ]; then ... fi` will be always true, because `SILENT_MODE` is never an empty string ;-)

Comment: tl;dr; change the `if [[ ... ]] then` to `if ! git --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then` and get rid of all the `exec` fd juggling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reiterate advice given [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/482418/23408#comment883300_482418):

1. Delete the `continue` statements from the `CheckGit` function.

   - They aren't necessary,
   - and — what you might not have realized — they cause,
     not only an immediate return (from the function) to the main loop,
     but an immediate return to the `while true` statement
     at the top of the main loop. 
     Therefore, as [Tomasz pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/482418/23408#482433),
     your `exec 2>&3 3>&-` statement isn't being executed.

General notes:

2. `if [ SILENT_MODE ]` is always true,
   as [mosvy pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/482418/23408#comment883301_482418),
   because it's just testing whether the string `SILENT_MODE` is non-null. 
   You seem to want `if [ "$SILENT_MODE" ]`.
3. But you may be fooling yourself. 
   `if [ "$SILENT_MODE" ]` is true even if `$SILENT_MODE` is `false` —
   all it's doing it testing whether the string is non-null,
   so calling `CheckGit false`
   will still result in the information being displayed.
4. And, even if you aren't fooling yourself,
   you may be fooling the person who has to maintain this script next week. 
   And, yes, that person might be you. 
   Your apparent logic is “if in silent mode, report extra information”. 
   That's logically backwards;
   it would make somewhat more sense to say `if [ "$SILENT_MODE" = false ]`,
   or else call the variable `VERBOSE_MODE`.
5. `$?` is very ephemeral. 
   It's always the result of *the most recent command.* 
   So, if you do

   ```
   if  check whether git is installed ; then
       printf "GIT IS NOT INSTALLED.\n"
   else
       printf "GIT IS CURRENTLY INSTALLED.\n"
   fi
   GIT_INSTALLED=$?
   ```

   then `GIT_INSTALLED` gets the exit status of the `printf`. 
   You need to set `GIT_INSTALLED` earlier.
6. Your test, `if [[ ! $(git --version) ]]; then`,
   tests, not “the return code” (as you say in the question),
   but whether `git --version` writes anything to the standard output. 
   That may be what you want. 
   That might be the best way to test whether `git` is installed. 
   But it might be better (and often, in general, is better)
   to check the exit status of the command.
7. A style note: I find `if`-`then`-`else` statements easier
   to understand if the “true” part is first. 
   Your script is saying

   ```
   if git is not installed
   then
       say that it's not installed
   else (i.e., if it's NOT not installed)
       say that it's installed
   fi
   ```

   Double negatives are confusing.
8. And, yeah; `exec 2> /dev/null` is handy
   if you want to suppress the standard error from 42 statements in a row. 
   If you need to affect only a single command, just put `2> /dev/null`
   (or `> /dev/null 2>&1`) on that command, as [mosvy suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/482418/23408#comment883304_482418).

Comment: With newer versions of `bash` (eg. 4.4.12), the loop state is reset on entering functions, so a stray `continue` will print an error message instead of returning to the outer loop. `shopt -s compat43` is needed in order to restore the older behavior (similar to `dash` and `zsh`, but different from `ksh`)

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you're saying about "the loop state is reset on entering functions", but it's good to see sanity prevailing. I was surprised that `continue` acted as a non-local goto when semantically, but not syntactically, in a loop.

Comment: it means that `continue` and `break` in a function will work exactly as at the top level; eg. `brk(){ break; }; for i in 1 2 3; do brk; echo $i; done` will print 1, 2, 3 (and will also warn about the meaningless use of `break`)

Comment: I'm not allowed to up-vote yet, but this answer helped a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

Your commands look fine, but the logic doesn't cover all cases. Notice that when you `continue`, the descriptors are not reversed.

Also analyse how this is supposed to work, and how it does indeed:

```
GIT_INSTALLED=$?
```

`$?` is the exit code of the last command performed. Use debugging to see this closer (`set -x`).

Also, as a beginner, you'd benefit greatly from static-testing your scripts with [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net/).